# get data the object with a filter

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object

Hi guys i have a question with objects in Javascript.
Ok, i've this structure

My Object

```
{
  "client": {
    "rpc2": {
      "testEstrobos": false
    },
    "rpc1": {
      "testParlantes": false
    },
    "channelServerId": 0,
    "channelClientStatus": false,
    "testParlantes": false
  },
  "shared": {
    "atributoServidor": "modificadoporTenant"
  }
}
```

I want to obtain`{ rpc1: { testEstrobos: false}, rpc2: { testParlantes: false  }  }`  but only with one condition. JSON can updated because at the end it is obtained by an API. I would need some type of filter like the función Like in SQL were I only obtain an RPC. I used the function **match** and **indexOf**. This last one does filter but would only give me the name without its structure

Comment: Does client always contain `channelServerId`, `channelClientStatus` and `testParlantes`? Do the properties you want from client always follow the naming structure `rpcX`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit tricky. First get the keys of your client-object and `filter` over it for all property with keyname beginning of 'rpc'. Then interate with foreach over the keys. For every key add to a new object a new property with this keyname and it's property.

```js
let obj = {
  "client": {
    "rpc2": {
      "testEstrobos": false
    },
    "rpc1": {
      "testParlantes": false
    },
    "channelServerId": 0,
    "channelClientStatus": false,
    "testParlantes": false
  },
  "shared": {
    "atributoServidor": "modificadoporTenant"
  }
};

let res = {};
Object.keys(obj.client).filter(key => key.substr(0,3)==='rpc').forEach(key => res[key] = obj.client[key]);
console.log(res);
```